# Bernoulli shift on $S^\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Why is the Bernoulli shift ergodic?  I know the proof for $S^\mathbb{N}$.  The best would be if you could argue from this fact to the integer case, so that way I can see how one usually goes from one-sided infinite to two-sided. (This seems to be coming up a good deal in my probability class.)

As a reminder, the Bernoulli shift is the left shift, regardless of if it's the natural numbers, where the first coordinate must be dropped, or the integers.  Ergodicity is defined by all invariant sets having measure 0 or 1.

Any type of solution would be appreciated, even if it does not expand upon the natural number solution using the Kolmogorov 0-1 law on tail events.  In particular, I have verified theorem 3 here, but cannot figure out how to check exercise 6. (I have the hint, but not the fact that the hint implies the claim in general.) http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/04/254a-lecture-9-ergodicity/

Comment: I have not checked, but couldn't we deduce the general claim from the hint and Dynkin's $\pi - \lambda$ theorem ?

Comment: @Stephane Laurent Yeah I had hoped so.  But the ingredient I am missing for that proof is the checking that the set of all sets (say for F fixed) for which that equality works is a lambda system.  The hard condition is that it's closed under disjoint unions.  Don't know how to take the limit under an infinite sum.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct to take the average of $\mu(T^n E \cap F)$ ? This makes more sense with  $\mu(T^{-n} E \cap F)$, no ?

Comment: Oops sorry, I misread your question and I thought about the noninvertible shift. Of course taking $n$ or $-n$ is equivalent for an invertible $T$.

Comment: First prove it for cylinders. Then prove it for finite unions of cylinders. I think then you can use an approximation argument: approximate (in symmetric difference) an arbitrary measurable set with finite union of cylinders.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to deduce the integer case from the positive integers case.
We will establish that a set which does not depend on any finitely many coordinates, must have trivial measure (this property is called exactness, and this is Kolmogorov 0-1 law). Instead of set we may consider a general function of $L^1$ and triviality for function means that it is constant almost everywhere.

It is clear that the case $S^{(-N,-N+1,...,0,1,...)}$ is isomorphic to $S^\mathbb{N}$, for every positive integer N. Also note that any function $f$ can be approximated in $L^1$by the conditional expectation $f_N=E(f|B_{-N})$ each depends only on the coordinates $-N,-N+1,...$.
But from the previous case each of these functions is constant.